# Dynamic Linq in Asp.net Core?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of Json data that I convert into a `List<Dictionary<string, object>>` I have to then filter that list and select some column out but the conditions of what to use for the filter/select will be different depending on different scenarios.

How can I dynamically build a linq statement?

```
items.Where(x => x.ContainsKey("A") && x.ContainsKey("B") && x.ContainsKey("C"))
        .Select(x => new { a = (string)x["A"], b = (string)x["B"], c = Convert.ToInt32(x["C"]) }).ToList();
```

Sometimes it maybe an "or" statement instead of "and". I do anticipate the where clause conditions will match the select conditions.

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What is it you actually trying to achieve

Comment: Assuming the following is also related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53036912/build-where-clause-dynamically-in-ado-net-c-sharp